# What's the difference between CH-DD and LSV+?

Tags: banking, switzerland

I recently moved to Switzerland, and one of the businesses I have to pay monthly bills to gave me two options (in addition to manual monthly transfers): "CH-DD" and "LSV+". As far as I can tell, both have the same properties: I give them a signed authorization once, then money is automatically transferred from my account every month; I have 30 days to contest the charges, and if my account has insufficient funds I receive a paper bill for the same amount instead, to be paid manually. So what's the difference between the two? Is there any reason I should choose one over the over? I asked around and nobody knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CH-DD is a direct debit facility offered by "PostFinance" on accounts held there. [PostFinance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostFinance) is essentially a subsidiary of [Swiss Post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Post) that is into banking. Most people in Swiss would have an Bank Account with PostFinance. If you do, it gives you better ability to manage the direct debits. [Other Banks may also give you similar facilities, but sure]

The LSV+ is a generic Direct Debit facility offered by most Banks in Swiss. If you don't have a Bank Account with PostFinance, you will have only LSV+

Your Businesses is holding an account with PostFinance and using their services to collect Direct Debits; [rather than banking with a bank]. Hence they are able to offer both CH-DD if you hold an account there or LSV+ if you hold account elsewhere.